# How can I add a new host to an existent Oracle ACL?

Tags: oracle11g, acl

I cannot find what command to use to add a host to an existent ACL on Oralce. Let's assume my ACL is called users.xml, how can I add host "remote.host.net" ? Notice I'm on Oracle 11gR2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you what you'd want to do is this:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL (
    acl          => 'users.xml',                
    host         => 'remote.host.net',
    lower_port   => <whatever>,
    upper_port   => <whatever>);
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: It worked, but I needed to ad the IP address instead of the domain name